# Why this PostgreSQL query is not displaying results with "Games"

Tags: postgresql

I don't understand why this query returns `"Music"` if I'm specifying `t3.name = 'Games'`. It should return `"Games"`. Any idea?

```
  Ad Load (1.9ms)  SELECT "ads".* FROM "ads" INNER JOIN campaigns as c1 ON (c1.id = ads.campaign_id) INNER JOIN taggings as tg3 ON (tg3.taggable_id = c1.id) INNER JOIN tags as t3 ON (t3.id = tg3.tag_id) WHERE (
 t3.name = 'Games' and tg3.context = 'categories') ORDER BY "ads"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Campaign Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "campaigns".* FROM "campaigns" WHERE "campaigns"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "campaigns"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = $1 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = $2 AND (taggings.context = 'categories' AND taggings.tagger_id IS NULL)  [["taggable_id", 2], ["taggable_type", "Campaign"]]
 => ["Music"]
```

**Update:**

Just to make clear the query, what I try to achieve is: Select all ads having a campaign with a category tagged as Games.

What my query above tries to do is

1. Join the campaign, tagging and tag
2. Try to search by tag (`t3.name = 'Games'`). But I'm getting a result returning `"Music"` instead.

The db schema is as follows

```
Ad
...    

Campaign
> ad_id

Tagging
> tag_id
> taggable_id (Campaign id)
> taggable_type ("Campaign")
> context ("categories")

Tag
> name: (i.e. "Games" )
```

Comment: If you want to quickly have an explanation/solution, please copy-past your complete create statement of your tables, your complete query and your `PostgreSQL` version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every ad could have multiple tags, so when you request for ads containing the `Games` tag, you might also get ads with both - the `Games` and the `Music` tag.

If you need the advertisements containing **only** the tag `Games`, then you need to exclude explicitly all the rest.

```
SELECT
  "ads".*
FROM
  "ads" INNER JOIN campaigns as c1
ON
  (c1.id = ads.campaign_id)
WHERE
  c1.id IN (
    SELECT
      tg3.taggable_id
    FROM
      taggings AS tg3 INNER JOIN tags t3
    ON
      tg3.tag_id = t3.id
    WHERE
      t3.name = 'Games'
    AND
      tg3.context = 'categories'

    EXCEPT

    SELECT
      tg3.taggable_id
    FROM
      taggings AS tg3 INNER JOIN tags t3
    ON
      tg3.tag_id = t3.id
    WHERE
      t3.name != 'Games'
    AND
      tg3.context = 'categories'
  )
ORDER BY
  "ads"."id" ASC
LIMIT
  1;
```